# Submitting multiple answers to a puzzle question

Tags: discussion

For puzzle questions / construction challenges like this one: [Longest sequence of moves where number of available moves increases](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/42020/longest-sequence-of-moves-where-number-of-available-moves-increases)
one may first come up with an initial answer and then later come up with an improved, better solution. What is the correct way to do this in practice? I presume if I added a third yet improved answer that would be quite spammy, so is it correct to instead edit my second post to include the better solution (at the top, or at the bottom)? Should I have already done that for the first post?

(also, is this the correct place for this sort of question?)

Answer (score 1):

If the second answer is an extension or minor modification of the first answer then I think it should be an edit.

If the two answers use different approaches then I think there is value in having two answers to preserve the different approaches to the problem.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. As a resident challenge taker, I often re-edit my posts if I find errors or extensions, sometimes multiple times in one day if needed.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Probably downvoting the man not the ball, to borrow from football. Downvoting answers on meta is free.

Comment: @RewanDemontay voting on Meta works differently.  Users often downvote to express disagreement with a post. One shouldn't presume a Meta downvote is about the person, though that is possible.